# How to integrate SQL Server 2008 R2 Reports on web site

Tags: project-management, version-control, visual-studio, sql-server, reporting

I am creating a site that is mainly used to view reports. The database is SQL Server 2008 R2 Express with Reporting Services. I was thinking of using Business Intelligence Development Studion to create reports since it integrates well and is easy to use. The site does not exist yet as the reports are its main feature.

I started using Visual Web Developer 2010 for the site since I thought it would work well. A Microsoft rep recommended that I use Visual Studio 2012 since it's compatible with SQL Server 2008 R2 and is the latest version. HOWEVER, it seems that report integration was stopped since Visual Studio 2008.

What tools should I be using for my reports and site? The database must be Microsoft but I am flexible about everything else. I am looking for tools that work well with the database.

I also want to use source control software that is compatible/works well with whatever IDE/software I'm using. Any recommendations?

Right now, I am the sole developer. I want to be prepared to expand to a small team once the project is underway and I want to be set up right the first time!

Answer (score 0):

If predefined reports is the main feature of your site, i recommend you to go a level higher and use some tool that let you create and design reports easily, like [DBxtra](http://www.dbxtra.com/).